# wsgi not importing system environment variables in Flask

Tags: python, linux, flask, uwsgi, wsgi

If I run flask app directly, I am getting environment variables, using wsgi I am not getting system variables,

wsgi.py

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

myproject.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
#protocol = httpa
protocol = http
socket = 0.0.0.0:8443
#shared-socket = 0.0.0.0:8443
buffer-size=32768
#chmod-socket = 660
#vacuum = true

#https = =0,foobar.crt,foobar.key,HIGH
die-on-term = true

enable-threads = true
vacuum = true

req-logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/cart-req.log
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/app/cart-err.log
```

myproject.py

```
import logging, re, subprocess, json, hashlib, os, jwt, mysql.connector, datetime
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask import current_app
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

import socket, logging, sys, os, pkgutil, importlib, inspect, logging.handlers
from importlib import import_module
from logging.config import dictConfig



class GetInput(Resource):
    def get(self):
        output = os.environ.get("MYSYSVAR")
        if output is None:
            return {'message': 'System Enviroment Variable not found'}, 404

        return {'user': output}, 200


cli = sys.modules['flask.cli']
cli.show_server_banner = lambda *x: None

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


api.add_resource(GetInput, '/getinput')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8443, debug=True)
```

This is Linus OS (Cent OS), I set enviroment variable like below

```
   added entry in /etc/profile
   export MYSYSVAR=4
    
   I also tried adding entry in below file
   /etc/environment
   MYSYSVAR=4
  
   source /etc/environment
```

Not sure, it is not working If I run with web gateway that is wsgi, but it works if I run directly myproject.py

Note: system inbuilt variable like USER working

Can anyone help how to fix it.

Comment: I don't think env vars should have hyphens.  Try with `MYSYSVAR` instead of `MY-SYS-VAR`.

Comment: I tried it, but same issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your env file in the virtualhost like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
SetEnv /dir/to/app/folder/.env
...
</VirtualHost>
```